# Random Crashing and weird console output

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I wrote an entire app, and I was just about to submit it to the app store, and in my final testing, I went back and added a few releases to ensure proper memory management was observed.  And since then, I keep getting these random crashes.  I've tried removing some or all of the release calls, I've tried retaining objects.  I cleaned the project.  I used `NSZombieEnabled` and that also is not helping.  All this to not avail.

Most of the time, the console says provides no help.  Usually the app loads, I put `NSLogs` in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, and `viewWillAppear`, and they all show up in the console, then it crashes.

Sometimes I also get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (and I know what that means).  But its occurring randomly.  So this doesn't make sense to me.  Thanks for any help possible.  I've written this whole app, and spent months on it.  So I'm really stuck.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you profiled for zombies?

Comment: Set NSZombieEnabled to YES! Just search for it

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I did try NSZombieEnabled and am getting no where.  Thanks though

Comment: "Adding a few releases" is not necessarily proper memory management. It could well be, that you release things that should not be released. But this is impossible to tell without more code. FWIW, the message about `current language: auto` means that the compiler chooses language dependent on the extension of the file (.m files are Objective-C). `gdb` is the name of the debugger. That has no meaning to your problem, so you can delete that.

Comment: No, but What I meant was a few things that needed releases didn't have them, so I added them.  For example, a viewController was allocated, but I never released it.  Simple, everyday things like that.

Comment: This is from the console.  Does it mean anything: `"NSZombieEnabled" to null value.`

Comment: Why do you think that those things need release ? Have you run you app with Leaks tool? And also if you're sating that app crashes at rendom places then it's almost certain that you're over-releasing the autoreleased objects.

Comment: I just realized I took a snapshot from the organizer window in xcode about 2-3 weeks ago.  Thank God.  I'm going to try to use that to solve the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Rudy. It sounds like you're releasing something that is still in use. I would go back to the version that was working and start adding the releases one at a time til it causes the crash. Slow but effective debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Build --> Analyze? It will search your code for leaks and other useful things you might have missed. Try that and see if it finds anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you "sometimes" get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, what do you get the rest of the time? Where does the crash stack indicate you're crashing? What messages do you get?

Random crashes usually indicate a timing problem. A common cause is accessing things on multiple threads. Are you? It can also mean timing differences based on network traffic.

Make sure the console doesn't indicate an exception rather than a memory violation. Usually there's something in the console that will be useful.

Comment: The times when it doesn't crash, it works as its susposted to.  I don't use any thread except the main in this app and this is no streaming of data.  The console either prints: bad access or `Current language:  auto; currently objective-c`

Comment: If you're seeing EXC_BAD_ACCESS, then you should hopefully have a stack trace that tells you where it happened.

Comment: Yea, thats been my previous experience.  But in this case nothing.  Thats why I'm so perplexed